# Angular2 - Click to edit form fields

Tags: angular

I have a form which pulls data from a service and displays it as follows

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'profile',
    template: `<h1>Profile Page</h1>
    <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="#prof of profileObject">
        <label from="name">Name</label>
        <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['name'] "type="text" id="name" #name="ngForm" [(ngModel)]="prof.userFirstName">
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <a [routerLink]="['../Dashboard']">Back to Dash</a>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: ControlGroup;
    userEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    public profileObject: Object[];


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private apartmentService: ApartmentService) {
        this.apartmentService = apartmentService;
    }


    onSubmit(form) {
        console.log(this.myForm);
        //post to rest API
    };

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this.apartmentService.getProfile(this.userEmail.email).subscribe(res => this.profileObject = res);
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }
}
```

When the component loads the template displays the data pre-populated in input text.

How can I display data in labels, and change it to input text on user click? basically want to implement click to edit functionality in the form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` to switch between two views:

```ts
    <label *ngIf="!isEdit" (click)="isEdit=true" from="name">Name</label>
    <input *ngIf="isEdit" (keydown.enter)="isEdit=false" 
        [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['name'] "type="text" 
        id="name" #name="ngForm" [(ngModel)]="prof.userFirstName">
```

Comment: perfect. I did few cosmetic changes to make it work 
`<label *ngIf="!isEdit" (click)="isEdit=true" from="name">Name: {{prof.userFirstName}}</label>
 <input *ngIf="isEdit" (keydown.enter)="isEdit=false" [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['name'] "type="text" id="name" #name="ngForm" [(ngModel)]="prof.userFirstName">`

Comment: I had a redundant `label` somewhere. Is there some other change? I can't find additional diffs.

Comment: on submit it's not going back to the previous view for some reason

Comment: I forgot about the extra submit button. Just add `this.isEdit = false;` to `onSubmit(form) { ... }`.

Comment: What if I have more dynamic elements ? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @YasarArafath you'd have duplicate entries for each element. One as `<input>` and one as only text (`<span>` or similar).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am using ngFor to display a table and in table if I click on a particular column then only that column should be editable.. what can be done in that case ?